# Is it possible to send an instance of NSData once through bluetooth from iOS device to iOS device?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I have a fitness app that I am working on and I am fairly new to Swift and Stack Overflow (so I apologize if my question is incomplete). I want to add a feature where if you are working out with someone with the app, you can quickly send the workout through Bluetooth to the other device. This would be just 1 array of data, and I would only need to connect to pass that one entity, not have a constant connection. I know that this is possible using server and client, but I would prefer Bluetooth if it is possible. Thank you!

Comment: Would Multipeer Connectivity work for you?

Comment: @Don I just read some of the documentation and it doesn’t seem like I can send an array of data to the second person connected. perhaps i’m wrong though. Is that possible through multipeer connectivity? there would be no data sent other than that one instance